# Move a dynamically allocated variable into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory, move

Given is the following C++ code:

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
int* num = new int(1);
myVec.emplace_back(std::move(*num));
```

If a move a variable with dynamic storage duration into a container (e.g. a vector) is it still necessary to delete `num` manually if `myVec` is destroyed (goes out of scope)? Is there any difference if I use `push_back` instead of `emplace_back`?

Comment: You're not "moving a variable". You're adding a vector element whose value is the same as that of the object on the heap.

Comment: motivation might be clearer if you use something like a `std::string` where the move constructor and copy constructor actually differ

Answer (score 3):

You are copying the value stored in `*num` in your vector.
It is not much different from doing this:

```
int* num = new int(1);
int cpy = *num;
```

Therefore yes, you must delete it.
Vectors do not magically handle lifetimes of objects when dealing with pointers somehow in your code.

---

You can use `unique_ptr`s if you want to have controlled lifetimes for your objects:

```
myVec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(1));
```

Anyway, this requires you to change the type of the vector from `std::vector<int>` to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>`.

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
auto num = std::make_unique<int>(1);
myVec.emplace_back(*num);
```

Allocated memory will be freed as soon as `num` goes out of its scope.

Comment: "Vectors do not magically handle lifetimes of contained objects." – But they do. Just not the lifetimes of objects the elements are copies of.

Answer (score 2):

In your case a *move* will not occur because you are using a *primitive type* `int` which will simply be copied.

But even when you *move* the *value* of an object on the heap into a *vector* you still need to release the memory because *moving* the value still leaves the *moved from* object in a *valid state*. It still exists and can be used. The effect of *moving* is that its value may have changed and so its value can't be relied on until you re-assign an new one.

It doesn't matter if you use `emplace_back()` or `push_back()` to *move* the value it still remains as a *valid* object on the heap so i still needs deleting *independently* of what happens to the *moved to* element in the *vector*.

So `std::move()` facilitates (but does not guarantee) *moving* the *contents (or value)* of the object - not the object itself so the *moved from* object still needs *deleting*.